# Apache reverse proxy - ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain not seeming to work

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, cookie

I can't seem to get the Apache directive `ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain` to actually rewrite the domain.

My directive is set as such:

```
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain "myinternalproxydomain.com" "thepublicdomain.com"
```

I use the Network tab in a browser and I can see the `Set-Cookie` domain is not being altered.  I see the Set-Cookie domain as either `thepublicdomain.com` or `.thepublicdomain.com`.  I have tried adding

```
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain "myinternalproxydomain.com" ".thepublicdomain.com"
```

I have searched and read the documentation, however I am failing to see why the domain of the cookie is not being set.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/myinternalproxydomain.com
ServerName myinternalproxydomain.com

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/my.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/my.key
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/my.ca-bundle

SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyHTMLEnable On
ProxyPreserveHost Off
ProxyHTMLInterp On
ProxyHTMLExtended On
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
ProxyPass "/" "https://thepublicdomain.com/"
ProxyPassReverse / https://thepublicdomain.com/
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain "myinternalproxydomain.com" "thepublicdomain.com"
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain "myinternalproxydomain.com" "thepublicdomain.com"
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain "myinternalproxydomain.com" ".thepublicdomain.com"

DirectorySlash On
ProxyHTMLURLMap "https://thepublicdomain.com" "/"
<Proxy *>
    AddDefaultCharset off
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
    DirectorySlash On
</Proxy>
<Location />
    ProxyHTMLEnable On
    ProxyPassReverse "/"
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain "myinternalproxydomain.com" "thepublicdomain.com"
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain "myinternalproxydomain.com" ".thepublicdomain.com"
    ProxyHTMLURLMap https://thepublicdomain.com /
    RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
</Location>
<Directory "/var/www/myinternalproxydomain.com">
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone enlighten me on where I should look to debug this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreversecookiedomain) directive has syntax:

```
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain internal-domain public-domain [interpolate]
```

Just like in this example for [`ProxyPassReverse`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse), the **order is reversed** (back-end first):

```
ProxyPass         "/mirror/foo/" "http://backend.example.com/"
ProxyPassReverse  "/mirror/foo/" "http://backend.example.com/"
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain  "backend.example.com"  "public.example.com"
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath  "/"  "/mirror/foo"
```

Comment: My example server domains maybe weren't clear in my question (now edited).  I have the correct order of the ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain.

Comment: Could you share the whole `VirtualHost` block, please.

Comment: Edited original question to include entire VirtualHost block

Comment: Now read my answer again. You currently have the backend last while it should be first.

Comment: Also, remove all the noise. You set same directives multiple times. That way you'll never know what did what.

Comment: I believe the backend `myinternalproxydomain.com` is first.  I renamed the servers in my example to be more clear.  I look at the `Network` tab in Google Chrome DevTools and see the domain is unchanged for the `SetCookie`

Comment: Rename it as many times as you want, but if it comes second in `ProxyPass` it should be first in `ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain`. Have you even once tested with my solution?

Comment: Thanks for the help Esa.  The order _didn't_ change the cookie _until_ I cleaned up and remove the "noise".  Once I removed the unnecessary duplicate directives the `ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain` began to work...on at least one of the two cookies.  One cookie has the domain `.public.com` and the other has `public.com`.  The one with the leading `.` changed and the other did not.  My proxy now appears to work regardless of the domain of the unchanged cookie.  Thanks for the patience.